# Pantalla en blanco Reactjs + Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

El problema es que al ingresar a mi sitio hecho con react y redux: http://190.190.139.142:4447/ muestra pantalla en blanco y con un error en consola: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si ingresamos desde un navegador Chrome con las extensiones para desarrollador React y Redux instaladas el sitio web funciona perfectamente.

Cual puede ser el problema?
Gracias!

Comment: Podés compartir la parte del código donde instancias el middleware? Creo que el problema puede venir por ahí

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo encontré, en tu `store.js` tenés el middleware declarado así:

```
const store = createStoreWithFirebase(rootReducer, initialState, compose(
    reactReduxFirebase(firebase),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
));
```

El compose es lo que te está rompiendo la app.
Si querés mantener Redux Devtools en producción te recomiendo que instales el paquete desde npm y lo uses así:

```
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

const store = createStoreWithFirebase(rootReducer, initialState, composeWithDevTools(
    reactReduxFirebase(firebase)
));
```

Revisen el proceso de deploy de la app, están subiendo todo, incluso la carpeta node_modules que es muy pesada y no se utiliza para nada, igual que los archivos no minificados.

Comment: Hice los cambios y continua sin funcionar, ahora tambien da pantalla en blanco con la extension activa.

Comment: instalaste `redux-devtools-extension`?

Comment: si, está instalada como dependencia:  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^5.10.0",
    "history": "^4.9.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^5.1.1",
    "react-redux-firebase": "^2.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-auth-wrapper": "^2.1.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-firestore": "^0.7.3"

Comment: error mío, respuesta actualizada tenés que quitar las devtools que estaban antes

Answer (score 2):

Al habilitar la extension se vuelve una exigencia para correrlo bien, comenta las lineas antes de compilar, quedaria una cosa asi:

```
 //  en caso de que no esté instalada la extension de redux comentar
  //las siguientes 3 lineas y descomentar la otra
  // compose(
  //   applyMiddleware(...middleware),
  //   window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  // )
  applyMiddleware(...middleware)
```

Comment: En donde encuentro ese codigo? digamos en que archivo?

Comment: en store.js donde cargas redux y la extension

Comment: const store = createStoreWithFirebase(rootReducer, initialState, 
    //compose(
    reactReduxFirebase(firebase),
    //window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
    //)
    applyMiddleware(...middleware)
);
export default store;

Comment: me sale error: applyMiddleware y middleware no estan definidas